# What do I do when Siwa no longer has any side quests?

Tags: assassins-creed-origins

I'm playing Assassins Creed Origins. I've been running around Siwa working all the side quests available to me, but now they're all done. And I'm like, what do I do now?

The last quest I did was Bayek's Promise, where I had to find the Amun constellation. The eagle doesn't see any more exclamation marks on the horizon anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's been a while since I've played this game, but [this guide](https://www.gamerguides.com/assassins-creed-origins/guide/walkthrough/prologue/main-quest-may-amun-walk-beside-you) may help. [neoseeker](https://www.neoseeker.com/assassins-creed-origins/walkthrough/May_Amun_Walk_Beside_You) also has a walkthrough. If you've done everything in Siwa, you should speak to Hepzefa to start the quest May Amun Walk Beside You.